# Passing variables from View to Controller using Html.ActionLink helper in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an enhancement to a project which needs to be able to delete one of many addresses that might belong to one person.  I have a controller action that does this based on a person's id and the id of the address.  My problem is passing the address id in my Html.ActionLink helper.

I have a view which gets multiple addresses per person in sql:

```
 var qryClientAddress = "SELECT    Address.AddressId,AddressType.AddressTypeDescription," +
                           "Address.IsMailing,Address.Street1," +
                           "Address.City," +
                           "Prov.ProvinceDescription," +
                           "Address.Postcode," +
                           "Country.CountryDescription " +
                           "FROM         Address INNER JOIN " +
                           "Person ON Address.PersonId = Person.PersonId INNER JOIN " +
                           " Client ON Person.PersonId = Client.PersonId INNER JOIN " +
                           "Phone ON Person.PersonId = Phone.PersonId INNER JOIN " +
                           "AddressType ON Address.AddressTypeId = AddressType.AddressTypeId INNER JOIN" +
                           "[COMMONDATA].[dbo].[Province] Prov ON  Prov.ProvinceId = Address.ProvinceId INNER JOIN" +
                           "[COMMONDATA].[dbo].[Country] Country ON Country.CountryId = Address.CountryId " +
                           "WHERE     (Person.PersonId) = " + id +
                           " AND Deleted = 0";




    //Load repeater if multiple addresses entered. 
    if (db.ExecuteStoreQuery<ExtendedClient>(qryClientAddress).Count() > 0)
    {
        RepeaterAddress.DataSource = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<ExtendedClient>(qryClientAddress);
        RepeaterAddress.DataBind();

    }
```

In the RepeaterAddress control, I get a list of addresses that belong to a client based on the id passed to my sql statement.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterAddress" runat="server">
       <HeaderTemplate>
    <table class="table1" width="50%">
            <tr>
                <td class="labels displayInput_75w">Type</td>
                <td class="labels displayInput_75w ">Mailing</td>
                <td class="labels displayInput_75w ">Address</td>
                <td class="labels displayInput_75w ">City</td>
                <td class="labels displayInput_75w ">Province</td>
                <td class="labels displayInput_75w " >Postal Code</td>
                <td class="labels displayInput_75w ">Country</td>
             </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                 <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AddressTypeDescription")%>'></asp:TextBox></td>
                 <td><asp:CheckBox ID="chkClientMailing" runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsMailing")) %>'/></td>
                 <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Street1")%>'></asp:TextBox></td>
                 <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City")%>'></asp:TextBox></td>
                 <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProvinceDescription")%>'></asp:TextBox></td>
                 <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Postcode")%>'></asp:TextBox></td>
                 <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CountryDescription")%>'></asp:TextBox></td>
                 <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AddressId")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                 <td><%=Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model.PersonId})%></td> <%--Add addressid--%>
            </tr>

           <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("")%>'></asp:TextBox>--%>

      </ItemTemplate>
       <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
```

I want the ActionLink to pass the id and the addressid.  At the moment I'm passing the id via the Model from the previous view's controller which works as expected.  But I can't figure out how to pass the relevent addressId in my ActionLink.

```
<td><%=Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model.PersonId})%></td> <%--Add addressid--%>
```

I realise it's not the greatest explanation but, in short, I want to pass addressId as well as PersonId.

I've tried creating a hidden textbox in my repeater with the addressIds assigned to them but I don't know what the syntax would be in the ActionLink.  Research has proved fruitless so I'm thinking it isn't possible.

Is there a better way of doing this without rewriting too much?

thanks
P

Comment: Why are you using a repeater in MVC code?

Comment: Good question.  It's a long story and perhaps a time for another SO post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's a hack, but:

```
<td><a href='<%=Url.Action("Delete", new { id = Model.PersonId })%>&addressId=<%# Eval("AddressId") %>'>Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: That's good.  This does pass both parameters as thay should be but I'm getting an exception when I hit "Delete". "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)."  The ampersand has a different meaning in the URL?

Comment: Hmm... Maybe try &amp; instead? Either that or a question mark ?

Comment: I'm passing each variable split by a '-' and parse them in the action and it's working.   Thanks Mike for putting me on the right path!  You're a diamond geezer (that's a good thing in case you're not English like me!).